# PowerQuery Cell Values Change Suddenly in between first two Applied Steps previews

Tags: excel, join, powerquery

I have a PowerQuery "qryQustion" in an Excel workbook. It joins information from two other queries together for the first line (SOURCE = ...), then the second line expands the joined table's fields.

I adjusted one of the two queries being joined together, and it yields good new results.
However, the subject "qryQuestion" query didn't seem to get the updated input, so I began investigating with its applied steps.

Turns out, the first line (SOURCE = ...) yields the good new results. 
However, the second line yields old results. I checked the expand function and its fields have nothing to do with (no similar names) as the field with values that suddenly go from updated to non-updated.

Here's the essence of the query's beginning:

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"qryInput1Updated",{"Keyfield"},#"qryInput2",{"Keyfield"},"qryInput2",JoinKind.Inner),
#"Expanded Column of Tables of qryInput2 Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "qryInput2", {"AddedField1", "AddedField2", "AddedField3", "AddedField4", "AddedField5", "AddedField6", "AddedField7", "AddedField8", "AddedField9", "AddedField10", "AddedField11", "AddedField12", "AddedField13", "AddedField14", "AddedField15"}, {"AddedField1", "AddedField2", "AddedField3", "AddedField4", "AddedField5", "AddedField6", "AddedField7", "AddedField8", "AddedField9", "AddedField10", "AddedField11", "AddedField12", "AddedField13", "AddedField14", "AddedField15"})
in
#"Expanded Column of Tables of qryInput2 Data"
```

Why would PowerQuery's preview show different results between Applied Steps?

Is there some sort of "recalculate all" for PowerQuery, or way to force it to recalculate?

Comment: It is not surprising because the preview shows the result of the selected step. The bottom most step is the final result to be loaded into the spread sheet or Power Pivot.

Comment: It might be getting the data from cache. Make sure to refresh the data once in a while. And clear the cache.

Comment: @KosukeSakai Yep, that's what I intended to see. However, the preview results changed in an unexpected way between steps. I figured out why eventually, and am posting why below.

Comment: @Dreekun I never saw that cache button there. Thank you!

Comment: @TravisBennett you're welcome. I can no longer count how many times clearing the cache solved things for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cause was an earlier group-by and aggregation: 
I aggregated by .first or .last but turns out PowerQuery sucks at maintaining the sort order. So, the preview was wrong. Instead, I needed to add a conditional column to calculate a value, then aggregate on min or max of that value. That fixed the misleading preview results, which I saw as an unexpected change between preview steps.